# equivalent frame in windows application and navigate from page to another page?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, frames

what is equivalent "frame" in C# application?
I must navigate from page to another page in windows application. I create master page and use some panel in page. I want to navigate from every panel to another page. how do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank for your answer. but I get find my answer!:)
in master page , should use some panel and create user control.
you design whatever you want in user control, and in button_click in master page, get instance from user control and add to panel.
this codes are:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
usercontol1 user=new usercontrol1();
panel.controls.clear();
panel.controls.add(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to create a new window in a project and create an instance and then in a code when sb will click the nav element you need to create an instance of than window class and than invoke using method showWindow()